# Substract a path to another one from the end of the path

Tags: java, path

In Java 11, given a `Path` `p1` representing `a/b/c` and a `Path` `p2` representing `b/c`, how do I obtain a `Path` representing `a`?

In general, I want to “substract” `p2` from `p1` “from the end”.

I realize that `relativize` is in a sense the inverse of `resolve`, but a little thinking reveals that it is not suitable for me, unless I missed something obvious.

[Feel free to skip this §. Analytically, the non-reversibility is because “addition” on paths is not commutative. I want to find a way of computing `p3` = `p1` − `p2`, where substraction must be understood “from the end”, whereas the `resolve` and `relativize` methods happen “in the other direction”, i.e., if `p3` is known already, we can find back `p1` with `p3.resolve(p2) = p1` (representing `p3` + `p2` = `p1`, with a non-commutative addition), or we can find back `p2` with `p1.relativize(p3) = p2` (representing `p1` − `p3` = `p2`, with substraction “from the start”).]

I am interested in simple and elegant code, not in efficiency.

Here is the code I use (neither simple, nor elegant). I suspect there is a much better way (possibly using already existing methods).

```
static public Path substract(Path longer, Path toSubstract) {
    checkArgument(!longer.isAbsolute());
    checkArgument(!toSubstract.isAbsolute());
    assert longer.getNameCount() >= 1;
    final Path substracted;
    if (toSubstract.equals(Path.of(""))) {
        substracted = longer;
    } else if (longer.endsWith(toSubstract)) {
        final int pathCount = longer.getNameCount();
        final int substractPathCount = toSubstract.getNameCount();
        if (longer.equals(toSubstract)) {
            substracted = Path.of("");
        } else {
            assert pathCount > pkgCount;
            substracted = longer.subpath(0, pathCount - substractPathCount);
        }
    } else {
        substracted = Path.of("");
    }
    return substracted;
}
```

[I could also invert `p1`, invert `p2`, substract using `relativize` (thus “from the start”), and invert the result. But that doesn’t seem easier, as I doubt I will find existing methods to invert a path (the result would be meaningless in many cases).]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Path.subpath](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Path.html#subpath%28int,int%29) and [Path.getNameCount](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Path.html#getNameCount%28%29):

```
public static Path subtract(Path longer, Path toSubtract) {

    if (!longer.endsWith(toSubtract)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
            "Path \"" + longer + "\" does not contain " +
            "\"" + toSubtract + "\"");
    }

    return longer.subpath(0,
        longer.getNameCount() - toSubtract.getNameCount());
}
```

Comment: That’s what I do, essentially, plus some adjustments to account for the empty path (I want substracting the empty path to have no effect), and returning an empty path if the substraction can’t be done.